# IsDateString class validator NestJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I have an endpoint that is responsible for bulk inserting some data into my postgres DB

```
  //Bulk insert
  @httpPost("/profile/bulk-create", 
    body()
      .customSanitizer(sanitizeToClass(BulkCreateDto))
      .custom(validateObject),
    checkValidation)
  .........
  .............
```

In my dto class i have a field that deals with a date value

```
export class CreateAccountProfileDto{
    .....
    .......

    @Expose()
    @IsDateString()
    @IsOptional()
    OpenDate: Date
 
    .......
    .......
}
```

The date value received is in the following format `2021/04/19` and every time i try to bulk insert into DB, the following error shows up

**OpenDate must be a valid ISO 8601 date string**

Does the @IsDateString class-validator not work with the above date format?

Comment: That decorator is an alias for `@IsISO8601()`
Feast your eyes: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator

Answer (score 3):

`@IsDateString()` is an alias for `@IsISO8601(options?: IsISO8601Options)`, which checks using [`validator`](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js)'s `isISO8601` function that checks if the string is a valid [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date.

From the documentation of `validator`:

> `options` is an object which defaults to `{ strict: false, strictSeparator: false }`. If `strict` is `true`, date strings with invalid dates like 2009-02-29 will be invalid. If `strictSeparator` is true, date strings with date and time separated by anything other than a `T` will be invalid.

So `@IsISO8601()` considers `2021/04/19` to be invalid, but `2021-04-19` to be valid.